# Meaning of "Like for Like" or "Follow for Follow"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, idioms

I just joined a Facebook group called "Tech Blogger's Community".

There are two rules for **Don'ts**.

> Don’t:
>
> - Post "like for like" or "follow for follow"
> - Write rude comments, only constructive feedback

What do *Like for Like* or *Follow for Follow* mean in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"like for like" is a short way of saying "if you click 'like' on something I post on Facebook, then I will click 'like' on something you have posted." It is implied that one or both people involved will not care about the posts that are being "liked," and that they are only doing it to increase their total number of "likes" any way they can to seem more popular and important.

"follow for follow" is the same thing as above, but for Facebook's "follow" feature instead of its "like" feature.

This kind of thing is usually considered anywhere from annoying to harmful, so many places do not allow it.